# ASP Core BodyReader/Writer Should I Complete it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

Should I call `CompleteAsync()` on `HttpRequest.BodyReader` / `HttpResponse.BodyWriter` when I am done with it or framework doesn't expect this (is there any effect at all)?

Answer (score 1):

> When I am done with it or framework doesn't expect this (is there any
> effect at all)?

Well, Interesting but important question I would say, By calling [`CompleteAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.completeasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and even calling `FlushAsync()` are all unnecessary. None of this is required because `Kestrel` will automatically flushes the response body every time you call `BodyWriter` or `BodyReader` no matter how much is written.

`StartAsync()` only needs called if you want to want to `flush headers` prior to writing anything to the `body`. And `ContentLength` is null by default.

You could have a look on our [`official GitHub thread`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26565) for more details.

Comment: All remarks in comment that you copied from are related to attached code sample and are mainly not generic. but +1 for finding it and efforts.

Comment: Yes, I already added the reference, and its doesn't belongs to my own openion.